# Filter Pandas dataframe by aggregated booleans

Tags: python, pandas, filter, python-3.6

I am working with a relatively large dataset (~400,000 x 76). I want to filter the dataset based on an aggregate list. Simplified example below:

```
full_list ={
            'bob':1,'rick':1,'jim':1,'tim':1,'bob':1,
            'janet':1,'denise':1,'bob':1,'jim':1,'jessica':1}
nameDF = pd.DataFrame({
            'Name':full_list.keys(), 
            'Value':full_list.values()})
big_names = nameDF.Name.value_counts() > 1
```

`big_names returns [True, False, True, False, False, False, False]`

I would like to use the results of `big_names` to filter full_list. Basically I would like to filter the original dataframe to only show the data pertaining to the results of the aggregated list of booleans. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think need for create `DataFrame` from `list` or some another way, because `dictionary` by design don't support duplicate keys:

```
full_list = ['bob','rick','jim','tim','bob','janet','denise','bob','jim','jessica']
nameDF = pd.DataFrame({'Name':full_list}) 
print (nameDF)
      Name
0      bob
1     rick
2      jim
3      tim
4      bob
5    janet
6   denise
7      bob
8      jim
9  jessica
```

And then filter by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return counts with same size as original `DataFrame`, so possible filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
big_names = nameDF[nameDF.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('size') > 1 ]
print (big_names)
  Name
0  bob
2  jim
4  bob
7  bob
8  jim
```

**Details**:

```
print (nameDF.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('size'))
0    3
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    3
5    1
6    1
7    3
8    2
9    1
Name: Name, dtype: int64

print (nameDF.groupby('Name')['Name'].transform('size') > 1)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
9    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool
```